# how to generate 2 combinations among n from an array of fixed size integers

Tags: arrays, dart, combinations

***Hi and thanks to read question,***

I'm taking part in a coding challenge. I am in trouble.

I would like from a parent that has an array of int, generate all random instances if we remove two in the first array (the draw) to put in a second (the hand). It's like a card game with 10 types of cards and you draw 2 at random.

I wrote some code that shows you the answer for a solution but I'm interested in all cases.

```
class Stack {

  Stack? p;
  List<Stack> child = [];
  List<int> hand = [];
  List<int> draw = [];

  @override
  String toString() => "hand ${hand} draw ${draw}";  
}

void generate( Stack _ )
{
  //...
  //  Generate all combine 2 from card
}

void main() {
  
  Stack start = new Stack();
  start.draw = [ 0 , 3 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 2 , 0 , 1 , 2 ];
  start.hand = [ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ];
  
  generate(start);
  
  //  A solution
  Stack aChild = new Stack();
  aChild.draw = [ 0 , 1 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 2 , 0 , 1 , 2 ];
  aChild.hand = [ 0 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ];
  start.child.add( aChild );

  print(start);
  print(aChild);
}
```

**And the result:**

> hand [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] draw [0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]

> hand [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] draw [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]

You can write code on Darpad. It works.

Comment: It's really unclear what those lists are supposed to represent.  And are you asking how to generate a random combination or how to generate all possible combinations of pairs?

Comment: generate all possible solutions. I have an idea. I'm trying to code tonight and I'll post if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found(coded) an algorithm that works.

```
class Stack {

  Stack? p;
  List<Stack> child = [];
  List<int> hand = [];
  List<int> draw = [];

  int cardToDraw = 0 , indexToDraw = -1;
  
  @override
  String toString() => "hand ${hand} draw ${draw}";  
}

void generate( Stack parent , Stack _ )
{
  //  Generate all combine 2 from card
  if( _.cardToDraw == 2 )
  {
    //  Reset
    _.cardToDraw = 0;
    _.indexToDraw = -1;
    parent.child.add( _ );
    return;
  }
  else
  if( _.indexToDraw == 9 )
  {
    return;
  }
  
  for( int i1 = 0 ; i1 <= 2 - _.cardToDraw ; i1++ )
  {
    Stack next = new Stack()..indexToDraw = _.indexToDraw + 1..cardToDraw = _.cardToDraw + i1;
    next.hand = [..._.hand];
    next.draw = [..._.draw];
    if( next.draw[ next.indexToDraw ] >= i1 ) {
      next.hand[ next.indexToDraw ] += i1;
      next.draw[ next.indexToDraw ] -= i1;
      generate( parent , next );
    }
  }
}

void main() {
  
  Stack start = new Stack();
  start.draw = [ 0 , 3 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 0 ];
  start.hand = [ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ];
  
  generate(start,start);
  
  print(start);
  int i1 = 0;
  for( Stack child in start.child )
  {
    print("[${i1}] $child");
    i1++;
  }
}
```

**And output console:**

[image]